# Is SQL Server merge replication transaction-aware?

Tags: sql-server, replication

If I have two tables with a one-many relationship that are replicated using merge replication in the same publication, and on the subscriber I add a row to each **in a transaction**, will SQL Server replication ensure that those rows are/are not applied at the server in a transaction, also?

Comment: If those tables are in separate publications. Then I'd say no definately its not.

If those tables are in the same publication? Good question, my instincts tell me NO. Would be good to find out for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Although I can't say for certain, there is convincing evidence that the answer is **no**.

First, the article on [using logical records with merge replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152507.aspx) states

> By default, merge replication processes data changes on a row-by-row
>   basis. In many circumstances this is appropriate, but for some
>   applications, it is essential that related rows be processed as a
>   unit. The logical records feature of merge replication allows you to
>   define a relationship between related rows in different tables so that
>   the rows are processed as a unit.

This seems to indicate that the method for grouping changes to multiple tables together is to define a (static) logical record mapping between them. If transactions could be used as an ad-hoc method for grouping changes, this ought to be unnecessary. Moreover, row-level conflict resolution doesn't conceptually fit with ad-hoc transactional grouping of changes.

Additionally, the definition of the [MSmerge_contents table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187355.aspx) doesn't include any place where transaction information could be stored. There are columns for identity, which subscriber has modified the row, column-level change tracking and logical record tracking. There is also a promising sounding `generation` column, but [a generation is all the changes between merges](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307356) so that's right out as well.

In summary, all available evidence points toward changes made in a transaction **not** being applied transactionally when merging.